# HTML table first column much larger than the second column

Tags: html, css, html-table

So I am creating a table in html using javascript. However, anytime I create the table, the first column is much larger than the second column, while the second column is extremely compressed.

I am trying to get the first column to be compressed and the second column to be the larger one, but for some reason it doesn't want to work.

[image]

```js
let rankings2 = [];

function generateTableHead(table, data) {
    let thead = table.createTHead();
    let row = thead.insertRow();
    for (let key of data) {
      let th = document.createElement("th");
      let text = document.createTextNode(key);
      th.appendChild(text);
      row.appendChild(th);
      th.style.textAlign='center';
    }
  }


 function generateTable(table, data){
    for (let element of data) {
        let row = table.insertRow();
        for (key in element) {
          let cell = row.insertCell();
          let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
          cell.appendChild(text);
          cell.style.textAlign='center';
        }
      }
}

let HotSeat =  [{pos: "1", name:"Ben Shapiro's Wife"},
{pos: "2", name: "Illegal Bookies"},
  {pos: "3", name: "76ers"},
{pos: "4", name: "The Post Office",},
{pos: "5", name: "New Orleans"}];

let table2 = document.getElementById("HotSeatTable");
let data2 = Object.keys(HotSeat[0]);
generateTableHead(table2,data2);
generateTable(table2,HotSeat);

window.history.forward(1);
```

```css
#HotSeat {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2);
}

#HotSeat td,
#HotSeat th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

#HotSeat tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#HotSeat tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#HotSeat th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  width: left;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="HotSeat">
  <table id="HotSeatTable"></table>
</div>
```

here is what the table looks like when I dont have width: 100% in td,th
[image]

Comment: `#HotSeat td, #HotSeat th {
    width: 100%;

  }` ??  that makes a lot ..

Comment: @G-Cyrillus when I get rid of the width: 100% the table compresses all the way to the left.

Comment: @johannchopin it gets filled in by the hotseat.js script at the bottom

Comment: okay, why not 50% if you have 2 columns ? or just `#HotSeat {     width: 100%;    }`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I just added an image to the bottom of what happens when I have width: 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove width off the `td` selector. This is causing your columns to look skewed.

Then add `width: 100%` to get the table to fit the width of the container.

Additionally, I am not sure what you are trying to do with `width: left` property, so I would remove it. Same with the `text-align: left` in your style sheet, you set `text-align: center` dynamically in your JS, rendering left align useless unless you really want them left aligned.

```css
#HotSeat {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#HotSeatTable {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#HotSeat td,
#HotSeat th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
}

#HotSeat th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="HotSeat">
  <table id="HotSeatTable">
    <table id="HotSeatTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Pos</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Ben Shapiro's Wife</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Illegal Bookies</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>76ers</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>The Post Office</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>New Orleans</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, Must have had an issue with not having a specific CSS for #HotSeatTable, thank you

Comment: @IDm The actual issue had to do with setting the width on the `td` selector, which is why the table looked so odd. However, setting the width on the table made the table look neat inside the container.

Comment: @cela thanks for the `Remove width off the td selector`